# Android How to save text from Edit Text to Shared Preferences on button click

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

Either I can enter a text on Edit Text or choose a pre-defined text from the spinner.If I choose from spinner, I am displaying it on Edit Text only. I want if I click on save button, the text from Edit Text will get saved to Shared Preferences. Right now, I am saving the text on `onAfterTextChanged()` but I want it to get saved on press of button. Please Suggest.I even followed the tutorials but didn't get much.

```
MainActivity.java


    private EditText message;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button save;
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            pref.edit().putString("autoSave", message.getText().toString()).commit();     
        }
    }) ;



    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    // message.setFocusable(false);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
    selectedContactList = dbHelper.getAllContacts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            alert);
    spinner.setAdapter(adp);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            // message.setSelection(pref.getString("AutoSave",""));
            String selectedItem = alert[position];
            message.setText(selectedItem);

            // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to
            // EditText

            // to bring cursor to front
            message.setSelection(message.getText().length());



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    /************************** saving custom message *****************************/





    ListView contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListitems);
    Resources res = getResources();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, selectedContactList,
            res, MainActivity.this);
    contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: write your pref in button's setOnClickListener(); what's the prob?

Comment: try my code...i have edited it

Comment: @MayankSaini Let me try it.

Comment: @bhanukaushik Did you try?

Comment: @MayankSaini onAddLocationButtonPressed can not be resolved to a variable. What to do

Comment: Have you added this

private View.OnClickListener onAddLocationButtonPressed = new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                            Editor editor = preferences.edit();

     editor.putString("autoSave", message.getText().toString()).commit();

                }
            };

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `onCreate` :

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
        pref.edit().putString("autoSave", message.getText().toString()).commit();     
    }
});
```

Please also note that you are making redundant calls :

```
final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

and

```
final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

do the same thing, so why not reusing the `pref` variable instead of creating a new reference to the same `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: actually , I am beginner. I was implementing the code like I did for afterTextChanged(). Hence getting errors.Let me just check it

Comment: Define "its not working", what error do you get ? Also, for debugging, if you edited the code and get errors, please share your code edits...

Comment: actually I don't want that onTextChanged() part. I only want data to get saved on the button click. so i removed it. Please see my edited post

Comment: not working means, if I restarts the emulator.The text that i saved on  button click is not there

Comment: Did you test this on a real device ? The code I provide will definitely save the EditText content in prefs, but if your emulator configuration does not retain sharedprefs, it won't work until you test on a real device ...

Comment: Is your above code complete ? You are not reading the sharedpreferences from anywhere... By the way, you duplicated the pref variable again.

Comment: just a min. I think I got it . Let me just check it

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way...

```
    private EditText message;
        Spinner spinner;
        Button save;
          @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
                    save.setOnClickListener(onAddLocationButtonPressed) ;



                    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
                    // message.setFocusable(false);

                    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spin_alert_message);

                    selectedContactList = dbHelper.getAllContacts();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            alert);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adp);
                    final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // message.setSelection(pref.getString("AutoSave",""));
                            String selectedItem = alert[position];
                            message.setText(selectedItem);

                            // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to
                            // EditText
                            message.setText(pref.getString("Entered", ""));
                            // to bring cursor to front
                            message.setSelection(message.getText().length());

                            message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                @Override
                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                        int before, int count) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                        int count, int after) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    // saving text after it is changed by the user
                                    pref.edit().putString("Entered", s.toString()).commit();


                                }
                            });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        }
                    });

                    /************************** saving custom message *****************************/

                    // for saving text that user can change as per need
                    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

                    // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to Edit Text
                    message.setText(preferences.getString("autoSave", ""));

                    // adding addTextChangedListner() to the Edit Text View
                    message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                int count) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // saving text after it is changed by the user
                            preferences.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();

                    });
                    ListView contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListitems);
                    Resources res = getResources();
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, selectedContactList,
                            res, MainActivity.this);
                    contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            }   

        private View.OnClickListener onAddLocationButtonPressed = new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                            Editor editor = preferences.edit();

     editor.putString("autoSave", message.getText().toString()).commit();

                }
            };
```

Comment: For the code you provide, preferences variable is not visible to onClick of the onAddLocationButtonPressed Listener, as it is only defined in the scope of onCreate, so preferences.edit() will not compile ...

Answer (score 1):

on `Button` click write this :

```
private OnClickListener onsaveButtonClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ReturningClass.setMY_NAME_PREF(getApplicationContext(), "Amresh");
        ReturningClass.setMY_USERID_PREF(getApplicationContext(), "8");


    }
};
```

`ReturningClass.java`:

```
public class ReturningClass {

    private static String MY_NAME_PREF = "mystringpref";

    private static String MY_USERID_PREF = "shareduserid";

    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("UserNameAcrossApplication",
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    public static String getMY_NAME_PREF(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getString(MY_NAME_PREF, "");
    }

    public static void setMY_NAME_PREF(Context context, String value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(MY_NAME_PREF, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getMY_USERID_PREF(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getString(MY_USERID_PREF, "");
    }

    public static void setMY_USERID_PREF(Context context, String value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(MY_USERID_PREF, value).commit();
    }

}
```

you can get the values like this :

```
String Name = ReturningClass.getMY_NAME_PREF(MainActivity.this);
String Id = ReturningClass.getMY_USERID_PREF(MainActivity.this);
```

With this code you can you can get or store the values in any of your `Activity` .

Comment: ReturningClass ?? Where is that coming from ?? The question is about SharedPreferences and you are not justifying at all the use of a completely different method... Also, getMY_NAME_PREF > what about variables/methods naming conventions ? Finally, please, please, remove the TODO Auto-generated method stub, that's just useless...

Comment: Apologies... just missed that class... Edited check it now

Comment: Apparently, you did not quite understand the use of SharedPreferences... *With this code you can you can get or store the values in any of your Activity* >>> you can achieve the same by getting a reference to SharedPreferences from anywhere so ReturningClass is pretty much useless... You also did not remove the useless TODO.

Comment: With this static getter n setter methods ... you can get the values in any of your Activity just by writing one line.